# Transforming String with Regular Expression: For a captured group: capitalize, replace spaces with underscores, and repeat captured group

Tags: regex

I need help with regular expressions. I have a String with the following format:

```
// <li>Blah Blah
// <li>Bleh Bleh
// <li>Foo Bar Blah
```

and I want to transform this String into the following:

```
BLAH_BLAH (Blah Blah)
BLEH_BLEH (Bleh Bleh)
FOO_BAR_BLAH (Foo Bar Blah)
```

Basically, the transformation is:

```
1. Remove the " // <li>". Call the remaining String X.
2. Capitalize X and replace the spaces in X with underscores.
3. Append X in parentheses to the end.
```

This is what I have so far:

```
Regex:
(\/\/ <li>)((.*)( ).*)*(\n)
Substitution: 
\U\2 \E(\2)\E
```

Which is *almost* correct except I don't have the space-replaced-with-underscore part.

May anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why regex? If the string is always in this format, why not Replace + ToUpper? Also, how do you get FOO_BAR_BLAH (Blah Blah) as the output based on your rule?

Comment: Folding the match to uppercase is not standard regex functionality, and I have only seen it in TextPad. Regex is not  a "programming language"; it's a matching expression. You can't use it in place of code. Specifically in this case, even with uppercase functionality available, you can't to all transformations in one regex match/replace because you can't "generate" characters in the output that aren't there in the input.

Comment: @shree.pat18 Sorry that was a mistake. I've edited the question with a correct example.

Comment: Cool. Question remains though - why do you want to use regex in this case?